# I am very new to Active Directory and therefore finding in difficult to connect to it via LDAP from my c# application

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

I want to connect to my AD from my C# application. Found some good articles but none of them helped.Found this piece of code but its not working for me, may be I am making a mistake in my connection string:

```
DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("TK5-RED-DC-35.redmond.corp.microsoft.com", "fareast\v-sm262", "sid16@SID");
ldapConnection.Path = "LDAP://DC=redmond,DC=corp,DC=microsoft,DC=com";
```

Basically my need is to search for the users by their alias in the entire directory, since I am very new to the concept of AD, I don't even know whats the domain controller in my case. I am attaching a snip of my AD. Please someone help me figure out the connection string in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace.

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context - without further parameters, this will connect
// to the default domain that you're connected to
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    Principal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Read more about it here:

- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Comment: I saw the article that you suggested, but can you tell me a little more about the formation of connection strings?

Comment: @SiddharthMishra: those are [LDAP distinguished name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366101(v=vs.85).aspx) syntax that you need to learn and understand in order to work with AD effectively

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but i have one question, looking at the snip of my AD above, can you figure out what should i specify under domain name so that i can serach for a user in the entire directory..please suggest